# =VLOOKUP giving wrong results in search

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have imported a CSV file into an Excel Spreadsheet with two columns.  The first has "GE 24" 11.6 Cu. Ft. Top Mount Refrigerator (GPS12FSHSB) - Stainless" as the first column and the "$679.99 in the second column.  When I search for "GPS12FSHSB" with =VLOOKUP (LOOKUP(D3,A2:B88,1,TRUE) I get the results from the column just above what I am searching for.  Sheet is sorted in ascending order.

Comment: `VLOOKUP("*" & D3 & "*",A2,B88,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Works perfect.  Thanks

Comment: Glad you were able to make it work even though I had a typo, `VLOOKUP("*" & D3 & "*",A2:B88,2,FALSE)`

Comment: did not pay attention to the A2 part.